# Changing sbt project's directory layout

Tags: scala, sbt

According to sbt tutorial on [changing paths](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/BuildConfiguration#Changing_Paths) I'm trying to change "target" output directory to "someother"

```
override def outputDirectoryName = "someother"
```

Everything goes fine except one: sbt automatically creates target directory with ".history" file inside. Why sbt does this when it supposed do create **only** "someother" dir ? I tryied to override all methods that are inherited from [BasicProjectPaths](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=ru#_gvea9IT4iU/trunk/src/main/scala/sbt/ProjectPaths.scala&q=BasicProjectPaths%20package%3ahttp://simple-build-tool%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc%22classes%22) (I use sbt.DefaultProject as superclass of my project descriptor)

```
override def mainCompilePath = ...
override def testCompilePath = ...
...
```

But sbt creates "target" folder in spite of paths overriding.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly seems that it should use the overridden outputDirectoryName in trunk...

```
/** The path to the file that provides persistence for history. */
def historyPath: Option[Path] = Some(outputRootPath / ".history")
def outputPath = crossPath(outputRootPath)
def outputRootPath: Path = outputDirectoryName
def outputDirectoryName = DefaultOutputDirectoryName
```

([from SBT's current trunk](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#_gvea9IT4iU/trunk/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala&q=.history%20package%3ahttp://simple-build-tool%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc&l=192)).

It may have been different in a previous version. Have you considered [raising a new bug](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/entry)?

Answer (score 0):

In sbt 0.13.5, I found a way to change the target folder by just re-assigning target in the build.sbt file:

target := file("someotherParent") / "someotherSubdir"

This only modifies the directory for the built classes and artifacts, however, the .history file is always in the project root directory.

Unfortunately, some other plugins (xsbt-web-plugin) seem to have problems with that - running the webapp via SBT console produced weird errors, when I switched back to the standard directory layout, these problems disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to achieve my goals (of all JARS in one directory, whose names contains the JAVA-VM-version) seems to be to specify an appropriate target for publishing - there are less restrictions on "sbt publish", and other plugins are not disturbed by a different directory layout.